# How to stop data in terraform from refreshing on every run while fetching the next available CIDR from IPAM

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-vpc

I am trying to automate the VPC creation by fetching the next available CIDR from IPAM. But with every run terraform is getting a new CIDR block while I use data. I tried to store the CIDR in parameter store but still its over writing whenever terraform is run without even changing the terraform code?

Can anyone help here?

```
#Preview next CIDR from pool 
data "aws_vpc_ipam_preview_next_cidr" "previewed_cidr" {
 ipam_pool_id   = data.aws_vpc_ipam_pool.ipv4_ipam_pool.id
 netmask_length = var.vpc_mask_length["standard"]
}

resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "vpc_cidr" {
 name  = "/test/custom-fields/vpc_cidr"
 type  = "String"
 value = data.aws_vpc_ipam_preview_next_cidr.previewed_cidr.cidr
}

#Calculate subnet cidrs from previewed IPAM CIDR

locals {
 partition           = cidrsubnets(data.aws_vpc_ipam_preview_next_cidr.previewed_cidr.cidr, 1, 1)
 private_subnets     = cidrsubnets(local.partition[0], 2, 2, 2)
}

module "vpc" {
 source  = "terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws"
 version = "3.19.0"
 name             = "dev-vpc"
 cidr             = aws_ssm_parameter.vpc_cidr.value
 azs              = formatlist("${data.aws_region.current.name}%s", ["a", "b", "c"])
 private_subnets. = local.private_subnets
}

resource "aws_vpc_ipam_pool_cidr_allocation" "ipam_allocation" {
 ipam_pool_id = data.aws_vpc_ipam_pool.ipv4_ipam_pool.id
 cidr         = data.aws_vpc_ipam_preview_next_cidr.previewed_cidr.cidr
 description  = "test-vpc"
}
```

**Workarounds attempted:**

**Option1:**

I have also tried the aws_vpc_ipam_preview_next_cidr resource but the vpc module doesn't accept it as input and throws the following error **The "count" value depends on resource attributes that cannot be determined until apply, but resource attributes are already applied.**

```
resource "aws_vpc_ipam_preview_next_cidr" "previewed_cidr" {
 
 ipam_pool_id   = data.aws_vpc_ipam_pool.ipv4_ipam_pool.id
 netmask_length = var.vpc_mask_length["standard"]
}
```

**Option2:**

I have also read about lifecycle unfortunately I cannot use them on modules or data and it only supports on resource. I have tried below code but no luck there either.

```
resource "aws_vpc_ipam_pool_cidr_allocation" "ipam_allocation" {
  ipam_pool_id = data.aws_vpc_ipam_pool.ipv4_ipam_pool.id
  cidr         = data.aws_vpc_ipam_preview_next_cidr.previewed_cidr.cidr
  description  = "test-vpc"
  lifecycle {
      ignore_changes = [cidr]
    }
}
```